# Kivy Carousel from a button

Tags: events, carousel, kivy

## What is missing in this code to running carousel??

I´m trying to conect the carousel in a button. When I run, it´s show a button, but the on_press nothing happens.
What is missing in this code to running carousel??

```
Builder.load_string('''
<tela>:

    Button:
        text: 'ir'
        font_size: 32
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        size: 150, 50
        on_press: root.ida()
   
''')

class acesso(BoxLayout):
    def ida(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(tela1())

class tela(BoxLayout):
    def ida(self):
            self.parent.ida()
    
class tela1(App,Widget):
    def livro(self):
        carousel = Carousel(direction='right',loop='true')
        for i in range(1,5):
            src = "images/%d.png" % i
            image = Image(source=src,pos=(1,10), size=(1250, 635))
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel
    

class CarroselApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.acesso = acesso()
        self.acesso.add_widget(tela())
        return self.acesso

if __name__ == "__main__":

    CarroselApp().run()
```

Comment: Please include whole code, with the imports. It's easier to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiples issue with your code:

1. You inherith from `App` and `Widget` for `tela1`. I don't know the effect of that, but this would be wrong somehow. Thoses are not meant to be combined. Your `CarroselApp` is already here.
2. Your `tela1` widget have a `livro()` method, but is never called. Plus, you create a widget   `Carousel` without really adding it to the `tela1`.
3. `tela` inherith from a `Widget`, so it wont layout the children. I'm 200% this would not give what you wished in the first place.

I guess if you replace `tela1` with this code, it might works:

```
class tela1(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(tela1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.livro())

    def livro(self):
        carousel = Carousel(direction='right',loop='true')
        for i in range(1,5):
            src = "images/%d.png" % i
            image = Image(source=src,pos=(1,10), size=(1250, 635))
            carousel.add_widget(image)
        return carousel
```

Note: please consider pep8 for your code. Using lowercase for class name is not usual and confusing.